# Xamarin (Forms): how to download and use an SQLite DB file

Tags: sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

my client has a simple SQLite DB exposed through an URL (direct download of the DB entire file).

What I have to do is to download the file and then use it in my app: Android and iOS.

I am already able to use the same DB locally: I have a copy of the same file that is online (not updated) in my assets and resource folders and I can use the data in it inside my app. The DB structure won't change; the file is updated every night to reflect the changes in their DB, so only record updates/additions/removals.

Anyone can give me any advice on how to achieve this result?

Comment: Sorry but what exactly is your question? Yes this is possible, but I think if you spend some time Googling you will find enough results which will get you a long way. It is kind of hard to guess what your exact requirements are and the question as it is now does not show much of an effort on your part. Please have a go at it yourself and whenever you get stuck somewhere you can post a concrete question, explaining the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you already have a url of this data file, then you need to separately  download this file and save it to local on each platform, and use `DependencyService` to call the method of each platform in your portable lib.

For the example of using `DependencyService`, you can refer to [Saving and Loading Files](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/).

For the downloading part, you can use some plugins for example like [CrossDownloadManager](https://github.com/SimonSimCity/Xamarin-CrossDownloadManager), which may make your work easier.

Or if you want to complement this work in your PCL, you can add a `System.Net.Http` reference in your PCL, then use `HttpClient` to download your database file, but you still need to use `DependencyService` to save this file on different platforms.